# SQL: Number of items that match labels separately

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following four tables:
[image: table setup]

What I'd like to achieve is a product filter, that:

- Lists all label categories
- Lists all labels in each category
- Upon selecting a label, it filters the product list so that between labels within a group, there is an OR relationship, and between labels of different groups, there is an AND relationship. This query is complete.
- After selecting one or more filters, it displays how many products the selection of that filter would add to the product list. I don't really know how to achieve this other than querying the number products of each labels, but that raises an n+1 problem which I'd prefer to avoid.

An example of what I'd like:

Let's say I have two label categories, color and size. They have multiple labels, there is red, green and blue for the color; and small, medium and large for the size.

- When the user selects RED and BLUE, I'd like to list products that are either red or blue. (As I said, this product query is done)
- I'd also like to list all labels. For colors, I have red and blue checked, but for green, I need to list how many green products there are. For sizes, I need to list medium, large and small; and the number of how many red or blue products there are for each size. **How do I write this query?**

**Edit:** 
What I want is basically the product filter on left on Newegg:
https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&IsNodeId=1&N=100163729

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result in a table form.

Comment: As mentioned, the question seems vague and unclear. Some sample data will help with understanding what you need.

Comment: What I want is exactly this: 
 https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&IsNodeId=1&N=100163729 - basically the product filters on left.

Comment: In e-commerce this is known as **Faceted Search**. These products are very demanding in term of database backend. There are full layers of data processing just to process this kind of functionality. Don't think that you'll find a (comprehensive) answer for a real-world application here in stackoverflow. Full commercial, expensive products are developed just to solve this problem.

Comment: @nXu This question was asked a couple of months ago now, you now have a few answers, maybe it is time to decide on which one is the best answer or if none of them are then some comments on them explaining why those are not the answers that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, It seems like you need a grouping by category and label.

If you want to use same query for listing all products and filter them you can check the value of parameter, if it is null you can show all.

```
Select lc.title, l.title,  count(Distinct  p.Id) itemCount  from Products p, Label_Product lp, Labels l, Label_categories lc
where
p.id = lp.product_id and l.id = lp.label_id and lc.id = l.label_category_id
and (l.ID = @label or @label  is null)
and (lc.ID = @category or @category  is null)
group by 
lc.title, l.title, l.Id
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `COUNT(*)` instead of `SUM(p.Id)`?

Comment: `COUNT(x)` checks `x` for being `NULL`.  `COUNT(*)` is used when that test is not necessary.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `JOIN` is done _before_ `COUNT`.  You _may_ get an inflated value!

Comment: i have changed it to "count(Distinct ..", that should work. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically construct (in your application) the following query

```
SELECT size, COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE color IN ('red', 'blue')
    GROUP BY size;
```

This will give you how many small, medium, and large thingies there are, given that you are looking only at read or blue thingies.

Each time the user changes the choices, you rebuild and rerun the query.  Suppose the user has picked some types and sellers, but not manufacturers.  Then the `WHERE` clause will look like

```
    WHERE type IN (...)
      AND manufacturer IN (...)
```

That is, you need to be ready to build an `AND` list based on what the user has picked so far.

*This is application code; it is not practical to do all the work in SQL.*

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
--for colors category
select l.title as label_title
, count(product_id) as number_of
from label_product lp
inner join labels l on lp.label_id = l.id
--where label_category_id = 'id_of_colors_category' --if you can use label_category_id directly, or if you must use title of category:
where l.label_category_id in(select id from label_categories where title = 'colors')
and exists(
  select 1 from products p
  where p.id = pl.product_id 
  --global rules for products, for example:
  ----and p.deleted = 0
  ----and p.category = 'cars'
  --rules for user selected conditions
  ----for example rule for sizes
  and exists(
    select 1 from label_product clp
    --where label_id in (....) --if you can use label_id's directly
    where clp.product_id = p.id
      and label_id in(
      select id from labels 
      where label_category_id = 'id_of_sizes_category'
      and title in('medium', 'large', 'small')
      )
    )
  ----example 2nd rule for types
  and exists(
    select 1 from label_product clp
    where clp.product_id = p.id
      and label_id in(
      select id from labels 
      where label_category_id = 'id_of_types_category'
      and title in('type1', 'type2', 'type3')
      )
    )
  --don't add rule for current label_category - for this example colors
  --end of user selected conditions
  )
group by l.title
```

Answer (score 0):

This was tagged with MySQL so here is a MySQL way of doing this.
Assume 1 and 2 are the ids of the colors RED and BLUE and that no size filter has been selected yet. Then the first query gives you each of the color labels with how many products match the size filter. Likewise the last query gives you each of the size labels with how many products match the color filter.

```
SET @selected_color_labels = '1,2';

SET @selected_size_labels = NULL;

SELECT l.id, count(DISTINCT lp.product_id)
FROM label_categories lc
INNER JOIN labels l ON l.label_category_id = lc.id 
INNER JOIN label_product lp ON lp.label_id = l.id
INNER JOIN label_categories lc2 ON lc2.title = 'size'
INNER JOIN labels l2 ON l2.label_category_id = lc2.id AND ifNull(find_in_set(l2.id, @selected_size_labels) > 0, TRUE)
INNER JOIN label_product lp2 ON lp2.label_id = l2.id AND lp2.product_id = lp.product_id
WHERE lc.title = 'color'
GROUP BY l.id;

SELECT l.id, count(DISTINCT lp.product_id)
FROM label_categories lc
INNER JOIN labels l ON l.label_category_id = lc.id 
INNER JOIN label_product lp ON lp.label_id = l.id
INNER JOIN label_categories lc2 ON lc2.title = 'color'
INNER JOIN labels l2 ON l2.label_category_id = lc2.id AND ifNull(find_in_set(l2.id, @selected_color_labels) > 0, TRUE)
INNER JOIN label_product lp2 ON lp2.label_id = l2.id AND lp2.product_id = lp.product_id
WHERE lc.title = 'size'
GROUP BY l.id;
```